# How to create a table to check if a value exist on other table, if the value is not a primary key there?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-key-relationship

I have a situation where I want to create a table so that when someone tries to insert a row in it, it will verify if a combination of some of these attributes exist in other table.

For example, say that a,b,c,d,e constitute attributes from table F which I am trying to create. I want to verify that a,b,c,d exist in Table G. Table G has as attributes a,b,c,d ; however for other reasons 'b' can not be a primary key and only has a NOT NULL constraint. Due to this, I can't simple let a combination of 'a,b,c,d' from Table F be a FK for this table which would solve the problem, because b is not PK.

Is there any check that could do the same as setting an FK on a,b,c,d that references table G inside table F, but wouldn't require b to be primary key?

If I didn't make it clear enough, let me know and I will edit it. I already checked the manual but I can't seem to find the right clause.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably get pretty close to a solution using an 'before insert' trigger.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html

If you look in the comments section there are some suggested methods to abort a 'proposed' insert based on some external factor. It's not 'by design' but it does appear to be possible.